# Htaccess: How to redirect a sub-folder path to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a news website, in this website i have a sport section in a separate folder like this:

http://www.example.com/sport/

I want to redirect users from `index.php` in sport to `/sport/ar/` using htaccess.

I did that for the main website like this:

```
Options -ExecCGI +Includes -IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ar [R=301,L]
```

I applied the same method in the htaccess file in the sport folder, but no luck.

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you need .com to go to .com/sport ?

Comment: no i need .com/sport/ to go to .com/sport/ar/

Comment: let me know ,try this : Redirect 301 /subdirectory http://www.domainname.com/subdirectory

Comment: The server responded with `Internal Server Error`

Comment: Is this htaccess in the sport folder of your site?

Comment: no i did it in the htaccess in the root folder not the sport folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Options -ExecCGI +Includes -IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^sport/index\.php$ /sport/ar [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "tried it ,it didn't work" can you please define that?

Comment: Is there an htaccess file in "sport" folder?

Comment: Remove the htaccess file From sport folder and put this rule in root htaccess, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: yes i removed the htaccess from the sport folder, it did not work, i made a meta refresh, it works now, but will this affect the SEO and social sharing  ?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use javascript to redirect .

or if you want to redirect special urls . use `GET` method and this .htaccess :

```
index.php?u=ar
```

with this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sport/([^/]*)$ /index.php?u=$1 [L]
```